# How to set a point as default value for a geography column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial, geography

I have this SQL command that creates a table with a `GEOGRAPHY`-type column for spatial data that is meant to store a latitude/longitude pair (a point). How can I set a default value for that column? For example, a point at (0,0)?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StationLocations] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Position] [Geography],
CONSTRAINT [PKStationLocations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(ID INT,COL1 GEOGRAPHY DEFAULT(CONVERT(GEOGRAPHY,'POINT (0 0)')))
INSERT INTO #TEMP (ID) VALUES(1)
SELECT * FROM #TEMP
ID  COL1
1   0xE6100000010C00000000000000000000000000000000

SELECT ID,CONVERT(VARCHAR,COL1) AS DEF_VALUE FROM #TEMP
ID  DEF_VALUE
1   POINT (0 0)
```

In your case

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StationLocations] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Position] [Geography] DEFAULT(CONVERT(GEOGRAPHY,'POINT (0 0)')),
CONSTRAINT [PKStationLocations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id]))
```

Comment: Just not to create double answer... can be also `DEFAULT geography::Point(0, 0, 4326)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best method but, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8267910) as a reference, you could define it [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5b3b5/1):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.StationLocations
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_StationLocations_Position
DEFAULT geography::STPointFromText('POINT (0 0)', 4326) FOR Position
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it directly. You could use an insert trigger in a roundabout way, but it's not a completely satisfactory solution.