# A bug in SQL Geography POINT Lat, Long

Tags: sql-server, geospatial

**Update:** this has been reported to Microsoft.

---

In a simple (SQL Server 2012) table with a `geography` column (name `geopoint`) populated with a few simple rows points similar to this. `POINT (-0.120875610750927 54.1165118880234)` etc. executing

```
select [geopoint].[STAsText](),
       [geopoint].Lat lat,
       [geopoint].Long long 
from mytable
```

produces this

```
Untitled1   lat long
POINT (-0.120875610750927 54.1165118880234) 54.1165118880234    -0.120875610750927
```

which looks like a bug, but it is too basic and should have been caught before release. So am I doing something wrong?

**Added info**

IT professionals should look for the details of Microsoft's implementation of SQL server on MSDN. As there can be differences in implementation. As per this case. As a proof of this I just checked PostGist's implementation of `ST_AsText` for a `geographic` column. This works fine! and result is as one would expect. Therefore the bug is in implementation of SQL. The correct result for the above example should be

```
POINT (54.1165118880234 -0.120875610750927 ) 54.1165118880234 -0.120875610750927
```

Dare I say there is a high likelihood that there are other bugs associated with functions working `geographic` columns. As basic functionality in this area has not been fully tested.

Comment: Why do you think there is some error, looks good to me!

Comment: "am i doing something wrong?" - at a guess, you've assumed that the arguments to `POINT` are latitude followed by longitude, rather than longitude followed by latitude.

Comment: when displaying [geopoint].[STAsText]() Lat and Long should be other way. 

I have double check returned values for STAsText() for both a geography point and a geometry point. 

For a geometry point the returned values are correct as per STX and STY property extensions. 

For geography points [STAsText]() returns the wrong values for POINT. It should be POINT (lat, long)

This is a bug which i will report it.

Comment: It's not a bug. It's `POINT (long, lat)`, as should be obvious when you can find plenty of examples when the first parameter is greater than 90.

Comment: It is definitely a bug. Check out the STAsText for a geography column. 
Truncating a value is one thing. Completely swapping the values is a bug which is the case here. Definitely a bug.

Comment: Okay. We'll try saying it another way. Look at the example in [`STPointFromText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933979.aspx): `SET @g = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);`. If you can provide me a link to a map showing the location on earth of that point (at a *latitude* of `-122`, as you claim) then you might have a point.

Comment: Andrew, please check WickedFan's correctly referenced linked from MSDN. Points are represented as POINT(lat,long,SRID). Consider a case where data needs to be converted from geography to geometry. There are several ways of doing this. One of which is to use STAsText which produces the text Point(lat,long) etc. This will NOT work. As the geography version creates the wrong text but the geometry insertion expected Point(x,y) etc. This method also allows for change of projection.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, please check the example i gave and my reply to Andrew. WickedFan also correctly provided the reference to MSDN documentation of the definition of POINT. In this case i am trying to convert large amount of data from geography to geometry and change the projection at the same time. Hence the reason for using STAasText and not the binary version. STAasText for geography should return the value of POINT as per definition on MSDN.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, put any value you like below 90. For geography version the STAasText function still returns swaps the values around.

Comment: @Farjad - I've pointed you at an example where a geography is constructed *from* a Well-Known Text, using a first parameter of `-122.34900`. Where on the globe do you think that this point is located? The convention in WKT is `long lat`, not `lat long`. This is different from the convention you may have expected but it's *not* a bug. What it may indicate is that because you *assumed* it was `lat long`, you've entered your data incorrectly.

Comment: Final note: if you think this is a bug, then submit a bug report to Microsoft instead of discussing it here. We can't help you to fix this bug, we are not Microsoft. You can disagree with me, but my point stands (as others seem to agree with my answer).

Comment: @AndrewT. , Without a doubt this is a bug. i don't live or die by stackoverflow. Equally i don't make comments publicly without thoroughly testing it. i needed to ensure this is a bug , as it may have an impact on other people's projects equally,hence my attempted consultation on stackoverflow. It is important that people on this forum equally act responsibly as their comments and marking has an impact on other people's projects. 
This has been reported to Microsoft.

Answer (score 17):

This is working as intended.

According to your question, you stored the data in this pattern:

`POINT (-0.120875610750927 54.1165118880234)`

then you claimed that the lat/long is reversed according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811(v=sql.120).aspx) of

`Point(Lat, Long, SRID)`.

You may realize that the syntax you're using is not the same as the one you claim:

`POINT(aValue anotherValue)` vs `Point(Lat, Long, SRID)`

Now, the question is, what does MS SQL do to the data?

Turns out, MS SQL interprets the data as Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) Well-Known Text (WKT), and thus use [`STPointFromText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933979.aspx) function since the format is the most suitable for 2-D point:

`POINT(x y)`

Now, the follow-up question, does it mean `POINT(Lat Long)`?

From the sample code

```
SET @g = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);
```

it should be clear that the first parameter is not latitude, but longitude (the range of latitude range is from -90 to 90 only), so now we guess that the format is `POINT(Long Lat)` then. But why?

As explained in [this article](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx),

> As you can see [...], the longitude is specified first before the latitude.  The reason is because in the Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) Well-Known Text (WKT) representation, the format is (x, y).  Geographic coordinates are usually specified by Lat/Long but between these two, the X is the Longitude while the Y is the Latitude.
>
> You may be wondering why the X-coordinate is the Longitude while the Y-coordinate is the Latitude.  Think of the equator of the earth as the x-axis while the prime meridian is the Y-axis.  Longitude is defined as the distance from the prime meridian along the x-axis (or the equator).  Similarly, latitude is defined as the distance from the equator along the Y-axis.

Comment: Note: This is just a result of researching and collecting related information. I'm not an MS SQL or GIS expert at all.

Comment: Andrew thanks for taking the time to reply to this thread. 
Andrew you mentioned the syntax i am using is not the same as i claim. 
The reported list is nothing other than what is produced by sql engine. 
The syntax is merely the return values of STAsText(). So it is NOT me that is changing anything. It is the returned values of the function by sql engine. As per MSDN definition the returned value for point is incorrect. One should be able to pick this text up and consume it to convert the point (with lat,long) to geometry version.

Comment: I see... then please clarify how you input the data. Did you use `Point(Lat, Long, SRID)` or `POINT (-0.120875610750927 54.1165118880234)`? Currently I assume you used the latter, and from your output, it printed the latter. But still, I don't find it as a bug. you may input with the former, but if it's printed as the latter, then there is nothing wrong. Similar to how I input 2014-12-6 then it output 12/6/2014. The point is, as long as the format is correct, there is no problem.

Answer (score -4):

This is a bug. Returned value for STAsText for a geography column swaps the Lat and Long values. Definitely a bug which people should be aware of.

Comment: No, you have it backwards, the y coordinate is longitude. People talk about lat/lon, but it is implemeneted as lon/lat. It is not a bug.

Comment: -John Barca and others. MSDN clearly defines point as Point ( Lat, Long, SRID ).

As i mentioned before. The geometry version of STAsText works correctly but NOT the geography version. 
So when testing this issue be careful not to confuse the two versions.

Comment: I think there might be a problem.  Take a look at my unit test:
     latitude = 40.584474F;
     longitude = -111.633491F;
     var location = SqlGeography.Point( latitude, longitude, 4326 );
     var point = location .ToString();

At this point, the variable point has a value of:
POINT (-111.63349151611328 40.58447265625)

That looks like a bug to me.