# Getting different answers using DbGeography and SqlGeography: Why?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, spatial, geography

I am using Entity Framework v6.1.3 ( DbGeography) and 14.0.314.76 (SqlGeography). Both of these are the latest versions.

DbGeography code

```
        public static double GetDistance(double p1Latitude, double p1Longitude, double p2Latitude, double p2Longitude, int SRID = 4326)
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography p1 = System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.FromText(String.Format("POINT({0} {1} {2})", p1Latitude, p1Longitude, SRID));
        System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography p2 = System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.FromText(String.Format("POINT({0} {1} {2})", p2Latitude, p2Longitude, SRID));
        return (double)p1.Distance(p2);
    }
```

**SqlGeography Code**

```
public static double GetDistance(double p1Latitude, double p1Longitude, double p2Latitude, double p2Longitude, int SRID = 4326)
    {
        SqlGeography p1 = SqlGeography.Point(p1Latitude, p1Longitude, SRID);
        SqlGeography p2 = SqlGeography.Point(p2Latitude, p2Longitude, SRID);
        return (double)p1.STDistance(p2);
    }
```

DbGeography gives 179403.75129861536 and SqlGeography gives 217842.34845013986.

**I have checked the calculation in SQL Server**

```
declare @p1 geography = geography::Point(-11.98260953020022, 54.51564130011218,4326)
declare @p2 geography = geography::Point(-10.55307433448692, 53.14334572793153,4326)
select @p1.STDistance(@p2)
```

The answer is 217842.34845014.
I  have also verified the distance in Google Earth Pro creating a line string

```
            <coordinates>
        54.51564130011218,-11.98260953020022,0  53.14334572793153,-10.55307433448692,0 
        </coordinates>
```

The length is 217832.

The Dbgeography call is:

```
double x = EF.GetDistance(-11.98260953020022, 54.51564130011218, -10.55307433448692, 53.14334572793153);
```

The SqlGeography call is:

```
            double y = Geography.SQLServerTypes.GetDistance(-11.98260953020022, 54.51564130011218, -10.55307433448692, 53.14334572793153);
```

I am at a loss to understand why the DbGeography result is so far out.
    Any insight?
    Thanks.

Comment: The usual issue for questions like this is people assuming that latitude is always passed first and longitude second. Check the documentation for the forms your using.

Comment: For a "fun" example, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297113/a-bug-in-sql-geography-point-lat-long). Because the `POINT` text representation is used for both geometry and geography, it uses `x y` coordinates, which map to `long lat` rather than `lat long`. I think you have the same issue here.

Comment: I have verified that the coordinates are in the correct order using the Watch Window in Visual Studio. I swaped to using PointFromText instead of FromText & I get the same answer now. I think the problem is that FromText coerced a Euclidean calculation instead of the expected spherical calculation. i.e. as you say, FromText is Geometry and I need Geography.

Comment: Really? Because if I put `p1.Latitude` in a watch window and step over the assignment in the `DbGeography` `GetDistance` method, I get a value of `54.5156413001122`. So, as I've been saying, the issue is that you're passing `POINT(Latitude Longitude)` to these text methods when it *should* be `POINT(Longitude Latitude)`.

Answer (score 1):

When using Well Known Text representation, the parameters to `POINT` are the `x` coordinate followed by the `y` coordinate. When mapping this to the geography, this breaks the "expected" convention since `x` corresponds to longitude and `y` corresponds to latitude.

So you need to reverse the order that you're passing the parameters:

```
public static double GetDistance(double p1Latitude, double p1Longitude, 
                     double p2Latitude, double p2Longitude, int SRID = 4326)
{
    System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography p1 = 
     System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.FromText(String.Format("POINT({0} {1} {2})",
          p1Longitude, p1Latitude, SRID));
    System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography p2 =
     System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.FromText(String.Format("POINT({0} {1} {2})",
          p2Longitude, p2Latitude, SRID));
    return (double)p1.Distance(p2);
}
```

This then produces your expected result of 217842.34845014423.